ReactJS Nodemailer not sending email
Trying to figure out how to send emails using ReactJS and Nodemailer.
In my client folder, I have App.js which looks like this:
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();

  const sendMail = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000", {
        params: {
          email,
          subject,
          message,
        },
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("success");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("failure");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      // 2 more inputs for subject and message
      <button onClick={sendMail}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

In my server folder, I have a file called app.js that looks like this:
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: "25mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "25mb" }));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});

function sendEmail({ email, subject, message }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "myemail@gmail.com",
        pass: "google app password",
      },
    });

    const mail_configs = {
      from: "example@gmail.com",
      to: email,
      subject: subject,
      text: message,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mail_configs, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return reject({ message: `An error occurred.` });
      }

      return resolve({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
    });
  });
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  sendEmail(req.query)
    .then((response) => response.send(response.message))
    .catch((error) => res.status(500).send(error.message));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`nodemailer is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Upon running the code, I am getting the "failure" message in the console, along with a 500 error.  Here is a screen shot of the entire error:

A question I found here stated that I need to enable the less secure apps feature on my Google account, but my account doesn't seem to have that option:

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Use app password from gmail, you will need to enable 2FA for you to see it. https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?continue=https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords?

I already created an app password.  I specified that in my server code above.  Or are you referring to something else?

I think your mail configuration is missing the host and port as stated in the documentation https://nodemailer.com/about
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.use(jsonParser);
app.use(urlencodedParser);


function sendEmail({ email, subject, message }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.gmail.com",
            port: 587,
            secure: false,
            auth: {
              user: "myemail@gmail.com",
              pass: "password",
            },
          });
  
      const mail_configs = {
        from: "from@gmail.com",
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        text: message,
      };
  
      transporter.sendMail(mail_configs, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return reject({ message: `An error occurred.` });
        }
  
        return resolve({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
      });
    });
  }
  
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    sendEmail(req.query)
      .then((response) => response.send(response.message))
      .catch((error) => res.status(500).send(error.message));
  });


 
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
    });

My sample postman GET request is in this format http://localhost:3000?email=test@gmail.com&subject=Test Email&message=This is a test email

Looked promising, but I received the same 500 error.

follow my sample, it should work, otherwise, you may need to check your credentials @JohnBeasley
